# WebHook sends old update telegram bot

Tags: bots, telegram

When I use WebHook method, this method sends old update. How can I prevent this?

```
else if (text != null && text.Equals("متن ارسال شود") && (update.Message.Chat.Id == WebApiApplication.chatId1 || update.Message.Chat.Id == WebApiApplication.chatId2)) {
     WebApiApplication.SenderCount = 0;
     int i = 0;
     String[] Array;
     TelBotEntities1 db = new TelBotEntities1();
     int count = db.SenderBots.Count();
     Array = new string[count];
     foreach(var dbItem in db.SenderBots) {
         Array[i] = dbItem.ChannelId;
         i++;
     }
```

Comment: Hello, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here , read how to create a [mcve] example and also check [ask] so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: how should I use offset or anything else to prevent old updates?

Answer (score 0):

Telegram Webhook will automatically resend failed updates, you can see it via [getWebhookInfo](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#webhookinfo) `pending_update_count` parameter.

You can't prevent this, just ignore first few updates after start program.

Comment: Try exit(); function, it is depends on which language you use.

Comment: I use asp.net, after all function I use return Ok();